# c command line arguments

Tags: c, command-line, command

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int convert(char *str)
{
  int i, number = 0;
  for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
    number = number * 10 + str[i] - '0';

  }
  return number;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int j;
  int c = convert(argv[2]);
  if (argc == 3) {
    for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
      printf("Hello, %s!\n", argv[1]);
    }
  } else if (argc < 3) {
    printf("Not Enough Arguments\n");
  } else if (argc > 3) {
    printf("Too Many Arguments\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

getting segmentation fault when giving less then 3 arguments.
on giving less than 3 arguments it should print "not enough arguments" but it gives error segmentation fault.

input:`./a raju`
expected output: `not enough arguments`

Comment: Using `argv[2]` before checking is a bad idea, I guess... Really, can't you proof-read your own code (not speaking of the crazy formatting)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int c = convert(argv[2]);
```

When `argc` is 2, `argv[2]` will be `NULL`. What do you expect this line of code will do, as it's executed first thing when the program runs?

Refactoring so that the conditionals below it form a guard against that condition, here's something closer to what you probably intended:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int convert(char *str)
{
  int i, number = 0;
  for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
    number = number * 10 + str[i] - '0';
  }
  return number;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc != 3) {
    printf(  argc < 3   ? "Not Enough Arguments\n"
           /*argc > 3*/ : "Too Many Arguments\n"  );
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  int c = convert(argv[2]);
  for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
    printf("Hello, %s!\n", argv[1]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

P.S. As `argv[0]` is typically the program name rather than an argument, `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` will be your arguments, `argv[3]` will be `NULL` and if you count them you'll count two arguments, not three; expect `argc == 4` when three arguments are given.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [getopt.h library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt). It handles all the standard features of command line arguments.